# Firestore - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

Im trying to sync FirebaseFirestore with my app. But, Im getting an error in Text(self.data.data.specialty)-> app crashes. IN cloudStore, I have: collection "SpecialtiesData", document "Specialties" and inside document I have specialty: "test"
what may the error be?

```
 struct Search: View{
@ObservedObject var data = getData()
var body: some View{
    
    VStack {
        Text(self.data.data.specialty)
    }}}
    
struct Data {
   var specialty: String }
class getData: ObservableObject {
@Published var data : Datas!
init(){
updateData()


}
func updateData(){
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    db.collection("SpecialtiesData").document("Specialties").getDocument { (snap, err) in
        if err != nil{
            print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
        }
        let specialty = snap?.get("speciaty") as! String
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.data = Datas(specialty: specialty)
        }}}}
```

Comment: Hi Mateus, I'd suggest to format your code to make it easier to understand. I also have the impression that you misspelled "speciaty" - it should probably read "speciality". Finally, can I recommend checking out https://peterfriese.dev/swiftui-firebase-fetch-data/ for an in-depth explanation of how to fetch data from Firestore in a SwiftUI app?

Comment: @PeterFriese thank you for the reply. But Im still having the problem. Speciaty was just misspelled here, in the code it was okay. After doing some tries, I think the problem is in "@"ObservedObject var data = getData(). Do you now what the problem may be?

Comment: can you share any error messages you are getting?

Comment: Hello @mgoya. I wasn't getting any error. But, I've already fixed it. The problem was in Firebase Directory Rules

Comment: Nice ~
If you could update your answer to add more details on how you solved this it would be helpful to others facing the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was fine The problem was in Firebase Directory Rules